# Using parenthesis in Batch

Tags: batch-file, parentheses

The following code:

```
    SET I=1
    IF %I%==1 (
        SET /A X = (3 + 1) %% 3
    )
```

gives error: % was unexpected at this time.

We can understand the error from the following:

```
    SET I=1
    IF %I%==1 (
        SET /A X = (3 + 1)
    )
g
```

gives error: Unbalanced parenthesis.

So now we understand the 1st error, BUT WHY there is an error (Unbalanced parenthesis)

Comment: There's no need to escape anything, _(other than percents being doubled in a batch file)_. Use ```SET /A "X=Arithmetic function/formula here"```.

Answer (score 0):

You need to "escape" the parentheses in the `set` command using `^`.

Combined/full sample:

```
   SET I=1
    IF %I%==1 (
        SET /A X = ^(3 + 1^) %% 3
    )

rem prints 1
echo %x%

    SET I=1
    IF %I%==1 (
        SET /A X = ^(3 + 1^)
    )

rem prints 4
echo %x%
```

Or, as commenter @Compo notes, you could also enclose everything you pass to the `SET` command in quotes, like so:

```
SET I=1
IF %I%==1 (
    SET /A "X = (3 + 1)"
)
```

Which is arguably nicer, especially when your formulas get more complicated.

Comment: I believe you'd find that escaping the open-parenthesis is not required, only the close-parenthesis requires the escape.

Comment: Neither need escaping; please see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74361069/using-parenthesis-in-batch#comment131277404_74361069).

Comment: @Compo you're right. By enclosing all of the arguments (command line) passed to SET In quotes you achieve the same thing.

Comment: Amazing, beautiful, Thanks so much. Yossi Moses

Comment: I have long code with many () and Christian helped me beautifuly, I don't understand the solution of "". and what I do many Else If. The solution of Christian is very nice for me and doesn't requires many changes. Thank you all. Yossi Moses

Comment: I tried to understand and I did also the enclosing with quotes and it worked completly. thank you you all so much. Yossi